# How to get the difference time of two datetime variables in azure logic app in milliseconds

Tags: azure, datetime, azure-logic-apps

I have created logic app in azure, in that I have created two variables `startTime` and `endTime` with this `utcNow('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ')` value.

I want to get the difference time of the above variables in milliseconds.

So, can anyone suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#ticks) and please refer to this expression:

```
sub(ticks(variables('endTime')),ticks(variables('startTime')))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Frank, If I want to convert  into milliseconds then I need do the divide/10000 right?

Comment: Yes, its interval time is 100 nanoseconds.

Comment: I'm getting this datetime `2020-11-11T13:55:06.44` value, but I want to convert into this format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ`

Comment: Maybe you can use this expression `formatDateTime(<your-dateTime>),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ')`, you can refer to this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatdatetime).

Comment: `utcNow('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ')` expression can return the datetime format you want, why do you still get `2020-11-11T13:55:06.44`?

Comment: Thanks Frank, The above comment not related to this question. it is different one.